# How to loop str_replace() using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

The idea is I want to loop in the token on MYSQL and replace it with another value/ string see my preview below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdG4W.png

```
  <?php

 $token= $_POST["token"];
 $replace_token = str_replace  ("#", "new data", $token);

?>
```

Comment: add a proper data sample and the expected  result..  .. your img is not clear ..

Comment: sorry edited now

Comment: the content of the image in not useful .. so add a proper textual  data sample and the expceted  result

Answer (score -1):

In case i understand it right, you want to select some stuff and replace contents within a specific field?
Try it with REPLACE (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
SELECT id, myNameField, REPLACE(myNameField,'#','newValue') as replacedField, someOtherField
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourCondition IS matched
ORDER BY yourWill
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it directly with sql query instead of going this way.

as per your question you want to do something like start loop for token value as its like *#* and url bla bla.. and you want to replace with proper value.

so just run sql query.

```
Update {table name} SET token {field name} = {'your respected data'};
```